# JSF + JBOSS 6.0 + Linux + java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source

Tags: jsf, jboss, illegalargumentexception, xhtml-transitional

We are using Jboss 6.1.0 in our local Windows development environment using faces version 2.1.19. The application that we use works perfectly fine. However, when we promote our code to the testing environment which is Linux with JBoss 6.0 server which uses faces version "2.0.2.Final-redhat-1", we are getting the error

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source".

Complete stack trace is pasted below. The server does not provide more information than this and we are finding it hard to debug. Any advice/help on this would be great.

The issue appears when I click a button on the page which in turn makes an AJAX call.

```
16:37:44,298 INFO  [stdout] (http-/10.23.212.109:8080-2) AUTH FILTER -- procesiisng .. /vcp-web/jsf/calendar/calResult.xhtml
16:37:44,299 INFO  [stdout] (http-/10.23.212.109:8080-2) leaving phase >> RESTORE_VIEW 1
16:37:44,301 INFO  [stdout] (http-/10.23.212.109:8080-2) Entering phase >> RESTORE_VIEW 1
16:37:44,301 ERROR [APPL] (http-/10.23.212.109:8080-2) @@@ DefaultExceptionHandler.handle() >> Uncaught Exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source 
16:37:44,302 ERROR [APPL] (http-/10.23.212.109:8080-2) @@@ DefaultExceptionHandler.handle() >> Uncaught Exception >> Root Cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source at
util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:38) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]  
        at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71)    
        [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:73) 
        [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:73) 
        [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:271) 
        [jsf-impl-2.1.7-redhat-1.jar:2.1.7-redhat-1]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:257) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-redhat-1.jar:2.1.7-redhat-1]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-redhat-1.jar:2.1.7-redhat-1]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-redhat-1.jar:2.1.7-redhat-1]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-redhat-1.jar:2.1.7-redhat-1]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) 
        [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) 
        [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) 
        [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at au.com.woolworths.vcp.web.misc.AuthenticateFilter.doFilter(AuthenticateFilter.java:54) [classes:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) 
        [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) 
        [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) 
        [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679) 
        [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]


        16:37:44,305 ERROR [APPL] (http-/10.23.212.109:8080-2) @@@ DefaultExceptionHandler.handle() >> Other Exception
        16:37:44,306 ERROR [APPL] (http-/10.23.212.109:8080-2) Exception in FacesHelper.setGlobalMessageByCode() >>     
        java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key 
        web.common.exception.unknown: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle 
        java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key web.common.exception.unknown
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:374) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:334) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
        at au.com.woolworths.vcp.util.helper.FacesHelper.setGlobalMessageByCode(FacesHelper.java:125) [classes:]
        at au.com.woolworths.vcp.util.exception.DefaultExceptionHandler.handle(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:55) [classes:]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-redhat-1.jar:2.1.7-redhat-1]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-redhat-1.jar:2.1.7-redhat-1]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-redhat-1.jar:2.1.7-redhat-1]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) 
        [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) 
        [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) 
        [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
```

Comment: The best solution is to ensure that every field in the XHTML field has a name and id associated with it. The issue in my case was that some of the input hidden fields did not have a name associated with it and request parameter was sent without a key. This caused the page to not render successfully

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to ensure that every field in the XHTML field has a name and id associated with it. The issue in my case was that some of the input hidden fields did not have a name associated with it and request parameter was sent without a key. This caused the page to not render successfully